# Why am I getting wrong times?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code:

```
x = 10

def get_date(submission):
    time = submission.created
    time_created = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time)
    time_current = datetime.datetime.now()
    inbetween = time_created - time_current
    inbetween_total = int(inbetween.total_seconds()) / 60
    # If submission is older than 10 minutes, return True, if it isn't, return false
    if inbetween_total > x:
        print(time_created)
        print(time_current)
        print(inbetween)
        print(inbetween_total)
        print(inbetween.total_seconds())
        return True
    else:
        print(inbetween)
        print(inbetween_total)
        print(inbetween.total_seconds())
        return False
```

The printing was for debugging. 
I'm trying to get the minutes inbetween time_created and time_current, but I'm getting weird values like this from a less than five minute old post:

```
2017-09-26 16:11:44
2017-09-26 08:29:22.995548
7:42:21.004452
462.35
27741.004452
True
```

Comment: `inbetween_total` is 479 minutes.  This means `time_created - time_current` is 479 minutes.  Show us `time_created` and `time_current`.  Maybe you have a timezone problem.  Also, `time_created - time_current` is probably supposed to be reversed.

Comment: Where is ``x`` in the ``if`` defined?

Comment: Is `submission.created` a `date` object?

Comment: If this post was less than five minutes old, how is `time_created` 7 hours later than `time_current`? That's what is showing. `time_created` = 4:11pm, and `time_current` = 08:29am on the same day.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I've updated my post so that it prints those variables as well.

Comment: Unrelated to the question: `time` looks like a good name for a variable, but should be avoided. It is "taken" by a standard module name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fromtimestamp()` is probably being passed a Unix epoch time which is supposed to be in UTC (no time zone).  But `now()` is in the local time zone.  To fix this, use `utcnow()` instead.